# Set focus on entry that is not visible in pyGTK

Tags: pygtk, barcode-scanner

I want to set focus on entry that is not visible in pyGTK for a barcode scanner.

If I set entry to visible false then I get this error when setting focus on it.

```
    /home/samuel/visitors-book/visitors_book/__init__.py:60: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_widget_event: assertion `WIDGET_REALIZED_FOR_EVENT (widget, event)' failed
  gtk.main()
```

Thanks Sam

Comment: I have also tried to set the vbox to visible false, but has the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do without a GtkEntry and capture the [keyboard events](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq03.002.htp) directly.

But is it so bad to have the entry visible? All barcode terminals I've seen confirm what is read.

Comment: I have used the keyboard events in the end.